# join if entry doesn't exists in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have two tables which are selected an joined,

Table1

```
PK    Val1    Val2     FK
1     a       b        10
2     c       d        11
3     e       f
4     g       h        12
```

Table2

```
PK    Val3
10     X
11     Y
12     Z
```

When I do a select on this both tables with an inner join and all the Val-Columns I get this result:

```
Result
PK    Val1    Val2     Val3
1     a       b        X
2     c       d        Y
4     g       h        Z
```

As you can see the third entry is missing.
What I want is something like this:

```
Result
PK    Val1    Val2     Val3
1     a       b        X
2     c       d        Y
3     e       f
4     g       h        Z
```

How do I have to modify the joinquery

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 On Table1.FK = Table2.PK
```

Thank you, Karl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 On Table1.FK = Table2.PK
```

basically, `INNER JOIN` returns record where there is atleast a match on the other table. While `LEFT JOIN` returns all records on the table specified on the *left side* whether it has a match or none.

btw, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is identical to `LEFT JOIN`

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f63f/4)

Answer (score 2):

use left outer join

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 On Table1.FK = Table2.PK
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```